# hibernate query too slow using criteria - ignored lazy loading?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I've realized a jpa + hibernate application but if I use hibernate criteria application is very slow.

The time difference is 10/20 times.

if I use this

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM PlantEntity u order by idPlant").setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
```

time execution is about 5 seconds

if I use

```
Session hs = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
Criteria c = hs.createCriteria(PlantEntity.class,"plant");  
c.setMaxResults(Integer.parseInt(length));
c.setFirstResult(Integer.parseInt(start));
c.list();
```

time is about 40/50 seconds

Table contains about 2000 records

PlantEntity has relation manyToOne and OneToMany both set as lazy.
When I execute criteria query, lazy loading is ignored and I notice, in log4j, that all relation is initialized

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>it.ciro.model.PlantEntity</class>
        <class>it.ciro.model.SegmentEntity</class>
        <class>it.ciro.model.PlanningEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://94.23.66.103:5432/db"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxxx"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxxxx"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="60" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="90" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

how speed up application?

Entity

PlantEntity

```
package it.ciro.model;
// Generated 13-giu-2016 12.32.01 by Hibernate Tools 5.1.0.Alpha1

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * PlantEntity generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "plant", schema = "public")
public class PlantEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int idPlant;
    private SegmentEntity segment;
    private Integer plantTypeId;
    private String name;
    private String coordinate;
    private String nfcCode;
    private String plantCode;
    private String picture_link;
    private String attached_a;
    private String attached_b;

    private Set plannings = new HashSet(0);

    public PlantEntity() {
    }

    public PlantEntity(int idPlant, SegmentEntity segment) {
        this.idPlant = idPlant;
        this.segment = segment;
    }

    public PlantEntity(int idPlant, SegmentEntity segment, Integer plantTypeId, String name, String coordinate, String nfcCode,
                        String plantCode, String picture_link,String attached_a,String attached_b) {
        this.idPlant = idPlant;
        this.segment = segment;
        this.plantTypeId = plantTypeId;
        this.name = name;
        this.coordinate = coordinate;
        this.nfcCode = nfcCode;
        this.plantCode = plantCode;
        this.picture_link = picture_link;
        this.attached_a = attached_a;
        this.attached_b = attached_b;
    }

    public PlantEntity(int idPlant, SegmentEntity segment, Integer plantTypeId, String name, String coordinate, String nfcCode,
                       Set plannings, String plantCode, String picture_link,String attached_a,String attached_b) {
        this.idPlant = idPlant;
        this.segment = segment;
        this.plantTypeId = plantTypeId;
        this.name = name;
        this.coordinate = coordinate;
        this.nfcCode = nfcCode;
        this.plannings = plannings;
        this.plantCode = plantCode;
        this.picture_link = picture_link;
        this.attached_a = attached_a;
        this.attached_b = attached_b;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_plant", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdPlant() {
        return this.idPlant;
    }

    public void setIdPlant(int idPlant) {
        this.idPlant = idPlant;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "segment_id", nullable = false)
    public SegmentEntity getSegment() {
        return this.segment;
    }

    public void setSegment(SegmentEntity segment) {
        this.segment = segment;
    }

    @Column(name = "plant_type_id")
    public Integer getPlantTypeId() {
        return this.plantTypeId;
    }

    public void setPlantTypeId(Integer plantTypeId) {
        this.plantTypeId = plantTypeId;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "coordinate", length = 100)
    public String getCoordinate() {
        return this.coordinate;
    }

    public void setCoordinate(String coordinate) {
        this.coordinate = coordinate;
    }

    @Column(name = "nfc_code")
    public String getNfcCode() {
        return this.nfcCode;
    }

    public void setNfcCode(String nfcCode) {
        this.nfcCode = nfcCode;
    }


    @Column(name = "plant_code")
    public String getPlantCode() {
        return this.plantCode;
    }

    public void setPlantCode(String plantCode) {
        this.plantCode = plantCode;
    }

    @Column(name="picture")
    public String getPicture_link() {
        return picture_link;
    }

    public void setPicture_link(String picture_link) {
        this.picture_link = picture_link;
    }

    @Column(name = "attached_a")
    public String getAttached_a(){
        return attached_a;
    }

    public void setAttached_a(String attached_a){
        this.attached_a = attached_a;
    }

    @Column(name = "attached_b")
    public String getAttached_b(){
        return attached_b;
    }

    public void setAttached_b(String attached_b){
        this.attached_b = attached_b;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "plant")
    public Set<PlanningEntity> getPlannings() {
        return this.plannings;
    }

    public void setPlannings(Set<PlanningEntity> plannings) {
        this.plannings = plannings;
    }

}
```

SegmentEntity

```
package it.ciro.model;
// Generated 13-giu-2016 12.32.01 by Hibernate Tools 5.1.0.Alpha1

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * SegmentEntity generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "segment", schema = "public")
public class SegmentEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int idSegment;
    private PipelineEntity pipeline;
    private String name;
    private String area;
    private String segCode;
    private String picture;

    private Set plants = new HashSet(0);

    public SegmentEntity() {
    }

    public SegmentEntity(int idSegment) {
        this.idSegment = idSegment;
    }

    public SegmentEntity(int idSegment, PipelineEntity pipeline, String name, String area, Set plants,String segCode, String picture) {
        this.idSegment = idSegment;
        this.pipeline = pipeline;
        this.name = name;
        this.area = area;
        this.plants = plants;
        this.segCode = segCode;
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_segment", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdSegment() {
        return this.idSegment;
    }

    public void setIdSegment(int idSegment) {
        this.idSegment = idSegment;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pipeline_id")
    public PipelineEntity getPipeline() {
        return this.pipeline;
    }

    public void setPipeline(PipelineEntity pipeline) {
        this.pipeline = pipeline;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "area")
    public String getArea() {
        return this.area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    @Column(name = "seg_code")
    public String getSegCode() {
        return this.segCode;
    }

    public void setSegCode(String segCode) {
        this.segCode = segCode;
    }


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "segment")
    public Set<PlantEntity> getPlants() {
        return this.plants;
    }

    public void setPlants(Set<PlantEntity> plants) {
        this.plants = plants;
    }

    @Column(name="picture")
    public String getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(String picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }
}
```

PlanningEntity

```
package it.ciro.model;
// Generated 17-giu-2016 9.26.25 by Hibernate Tools 5.1.0.Alpha1

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Planning generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "planning", schema = "public")
public class PlanningEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int idPlanning;
    private PlanningEntity planning;
    private PlantEntity plant;
    private ServiceEntity service;
    private UserEntity user;
    private Date schedulingData;
    private Date completationData;
    private Integer result;
    private Integer status;



    private String planningType;
    private Set plannings = new HashSet(0);
    private Set planningDetails = new HashSet(0);

    public PlanningEntity() {
    }

    public PlanningEntity(int idPlanning, PlantEntity plant, ServiceEntity service, UserEntity user, Date schedulingData) {
        this.idPlanning = idPlanning;
        this.plant = plant;
        this.service = service;
        this.user = user;
        this.schedulingData = schedulingData;
    }

    public PlanningEntity(int idPlanning, PlanningEntity planning, PlantEntity plant, ServiceEntity service, UserEntity user, Date schedulingData,
            Date completationData, Integer result, Integer status, Set plannings, Set planningDetails) {
        this.idPlanning = idPlanning;
        this.planning = planning;
        this.plant = plant;
        this.service = service;
        this.user = user;
        this.schedulingData = schedulingData;
        this.completationData = completationData;
        this.result = result;
        this.status = status;
        this.plannings = plannings;
        this.planningDetails = planningDetails;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_planning", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdPlanning() {
        return this.idPlanning;
    }

    public void setIdPlanning(int idPlanning) {
        this.idPlanning = idPlanning;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_planning")
    public PlanningEntity getPlanning() {
        return this.planning;
    }

    public void setPlanning(PlanningEntity planning) {
        this.planning = planning;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "plant_id", nullable = false)
    public PlantEntity getPlant() {
        return this.plant;
    }

    public void setPlant(PlantEntity plant) {
        this.plant = plant;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", nullable = false)
    public ServiceEntity getService() {
        return this.service;
    }

    public void setService(ServiceEntity service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public UserEntity getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserEntity user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "scheduling_data", nullable = false, length = 13)
    public Date getSchedulingData() {
        return this.schedulingData;
    }

    public void setSchedulingData(Date schedulingData) {
        this.schedulingData = schedulingData;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "completation_data", length = 29)
    public Date getCompletationData() {
        return this.completationData;
    }

    public void setCompletationData(Date completationData) {
        this.completationData = completationData;
    }

    @Column(name = "result")
    public Integer getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }

    public void setResult(Integer result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Column(name = "status")
    public Integer getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Column(name = "planning_type")
    public String getPlanningType() {
        return planningType;
    }

    public void setPlanningType(String planningType) {
        this.planningType = planningType;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "planning")
    public Set<PlanningEntity> getPlannings() {
        return this.plannings;
    }

    public void setPlannings(Set<PlanningEntity> plannings) {
        this.plannings = plannings;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "planning")
    @OrderBy("idPlanningDetail")
    public Set<PlanningDetailEntity> getPlanningDetails() {
        return this.planningDetails;
    }

    public void setPlanningDetails(Set<PlanningDetailEntity> planningDetails) {
        this.planningDetails = planningDetails;
    }

}
```

Comment: and you need to use criteria query anyway?

Comment: I come from doctrine orm where the use of the criteria allowed to do very complex queries with minimum effort . I have to get the solution that provides the best performance .

Comment: Turn on Hibernate query logging to see what happens under the hood. And just to note: 5 seconds for the JPQL query is still wickedly slow. It should be milliseconds, not seconds. And for completeness I would also post the entity class so the JPA annotations and mappings are visible.

Comment: ok add entity and change persistence add statistic for hibernate

Comment: Why would anyone want to throw away vendor independence and use HIbernate Criteria when you have JPA Criteria?!

Comment: you suggest to use this system http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria

Comment: Try to remove 'order by idPlant' from JPA query and compare result.

Comment: @Andrew same result.

Comment: The entities look very much okay. I'd still be interested to see the hibernate query log to see what queries are being invoked under the hood especially when the criteria is used.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. Response time ~ 120 seconds with `hibernate`, 0.2 second in `SQL Developper`
I have removed in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` the following line:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</property>
```

and the performance issue has gone.